# Splitting an array into sequential groups

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array with elements `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...]`. I wish to split this up as follows: `[[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], ...]`. I am not sure how to do this because the elements in each split must be repeated, and I am unsure of how to create these repeated elements. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip()` to create 3-tuples, and then use `list()` to transform the resulting tuples into lists.

```py
data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Prints [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
print(list(list(item) for item in zip(data, data[1:], data[2:])))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a comprehension:

```
N = 3
l = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

ll = [l[i:i+N] for i in range(len(l)-N+1)]
```

Output:

```
>>> ll
[[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a module "more_itertools" that has method that creates triples from a list:

```
import more_itertools
out = list(more_itertools.triplewise(lst))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)]
```

It's not a built-in module, so you'll have to install it (pip or conda or whatever you use) beforehand however.

Answer (score 1):

The `zip` idea generalised for varying chunk size:

```
lst = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
result = list(zip(*(lst[i:] for i in range(3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` and comprehension, suggested above, are probably the ways to go in "real life", but in order to better understand the problem, consider this very simple approach:

```
data = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

result = []

for i in range(0,len(data)-2):
    result.append([data[i],data[i+1],data[i+2]])

print(result)
```

Comment: The `0` in the `range()` is redundant.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark you are absolutely right, but I was trying to make the code easier to understand, and I think adding that 0 helps in this regard.